# Get function and class name when carret change

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, function, sdk, caret

How can i get the name of the function and its class when the
caret change position in a code file, using `VS SDK 2010`

I am using `Editor Text Adornment` template as a start and `c#`.

Thanks.